# custom protocol handler via powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

QUESTION ANSWERED.. I have edited this question to the working solution.

---

Here's the scenerio.
Windows 10 workstation with Jitsi VOIP software installed.
I made a protocol handler for SIP: with this registry entry..

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip]
@="URL: SIP Protocol handler"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jitsi\\sc-logo.ico"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sip\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jitsi\\Jitsi.exe\" %1"
```

This part works. Entering `sip:1234567890` as a run command dials the number.

What I want to do is create a new protocol named CHK: that does a http request to a local webserver, and if the webserver 
responds with 0, dial the number. If the response is 1, show a message "this number can't be dialed"

Here is the registry entry I made for this new chk protocol

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chk]
@="URL: CHK Protocol handler"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chk\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jitsi\\sc-logo.ico"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chk\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chk\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chk\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\"
-File C:\\DNC\\dnc.ps1 %1"
```

Even though this is nearly identical to SIP reg entry, when I try running `chk:1234567890` I get an error "Apllication not found" , so 
something is not right with the open comand....

edit: I was right, it was the open command.. I had the quotes in wrong place

and the content of the dnc.ps1 script...

```
$w=$args[0]

$chprot,$num = $w.split(':',2)

$url = "http://server/numchk.php?ph=$num"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString($url)

if ($webpage -match "0"){ 

$launch = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jitsi\Jitsi.exe"
$prot = 'sip:'
$arguments = $prot + $num
start-process $launch $arguments        

} Else {

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("CANT DIAL $num ",0,"",0x0)
}
```

If I run the script via run command powershell -noexit -File c:\DNC\dnc.ps1 chk:1234567890
I can see the script is doing the right thing, dialing numbers if response is zero, show can't dial message if response is 1.

Again.. I think the problem is with the registry entry... specifilly the command/open part...

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chk\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -File C:\\DNC\\dnc.ps1\" %1"
```

Some trick to passing an argument to an argument I am missing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a quote in the wrong place, so it's not looking for "powershell.exe", it's looking for a file named "powershell.exe -File C:\DNC\dnc.ps1".

Does this work?

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\chk\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" -File C:\\DNC\\dnc.ps1 %1"
```

Comment: BINGO! That was it. THANK YOU ! ! ! !